# Does proving only one-one or onto suffice for showing biection in order isomorphism?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

In order to show that $P \cong Q$ we show that $a \leq b \Rightarrow \phi(a) \leq \phi(b)$ and then we show bijection. Note here, $P,Q$ are ordered sets.
My professor told me that here showing only onto suffices the condition for bijection. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Are $P$ and $Q$ finite and equinumerous?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes that is what is to be shown

Comment: Do we assume $\phi$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: Notice that even if $\phi$ is bijective and order-preserving, it's not necessarily an order-isomorphism. For example, if $P$ is the four-element lattice which is not a chain and $Q$ a four-element chain, we can have $a\leq b$ implies $\phi(a)\leq\phi(b)$, but obviously, we cannot have the reverse implication.